# change the scale of plot axis in matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot

I am plotting a time graph, where the values are my data and indexes are my time index. 
Now my x-axis is shown as index right now, looks like `0, 1, 2, 3, 4` but I wish to map it my to my time vector with something like

```
time(index) %output would look like 2012, 1995 etc
```

so how can I "normalize" my x-axis?

thanks

Comment: Can you give an example to the possible values of `index` and `time`? why not simply use `plot(time,data)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data is contained in the vector `data` and `index` are the indices you want to visualize:

```
plot(time(index), data(index))
```

will do. This is also explained in the MATLAB help for [plot](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/releases/R2011b/techdoc/ref/plot.html).